# List Jenkins build numbers in drop down

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm having  2 plans.
One for **build**; another for **deployment**

I'm trying to list **build** job's build number to the **deployment** Jenkins plan in drop down.

I can able to list all the build numbers with the following code

```
def jobname="Build"
def list=[]
hudson.model.AbstractProject<?, ?> otherJob = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(jobname, hudson.model.AbstractProject.class)
hudson.util.RunList<?> builds = otherJob.getBuilds().overThresholdOnly(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
builds.each{run -> list.add(run.displayName) }
list
```

I need the list of build numbers of **build** plan  in the drop down of **deployment** plan  which is not yet  deployed in the  **deployment** plan .

Eg:

There were totally 100's of build done in **build** plan. Among that  build number (1..10, 40..80) was deployed in **deployment** plan.
I need to list remaining (11..39, 81-100) build numbers in the **deployment** plan .

Simply , 
deployment plan  drop down contains values = : **build** plan build number - **deployment** plan build number